# Project Euler #21: Program runs forever

Tags: java

I'm trying to do Project Euler #21:

> Let `d(n)` be defined as the sum of proper divisors of `n` (numbers less than `n` which divide evenly into `n`).
>
> If `d(a) = b` and `d(b) = a`, where `a ≠ b`, then `a` and `b` are an amicable pair and each of `a` and `b` are called amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore `d(220) = 284`. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so `d(284) = 220`.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

Here's my attempt:

```
public class Problem21 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 10000; j++) {
                if (isAmicablePair(i, j)) {
                    System.out.println("(i, j) = (" + i + ", " + j + ")");
                    total += (i + j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum is " + total);
    }

    public static boolean isAmicablePair(int a, int b) {
        return (sumOfProperDivisors(a) == b && sumOfProperDivisors(b) == a && a != b);
    }

    public static int sumOfProperDivisors(int n) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            if (isProperDivisor(i, n)) {
                total += i;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static boolean isProperDivisor(int candidate, int n) {
        return (n % candidate == 0 && n != candidate);
    }
}
```

The print statement I put in main produces:

```
(i, j) = (220, 284)
(i, j) = (284, 220)
(i, j) = (1184, 1210)
(i, j) = (1210, 1184)
(i, j) = (2620, 2924)
(i, j) = (2924, 2620)
```

1) After several minutes, so it's definitely too slow.

2) Another issue is that each pair crops up twice, which I definitely don't want.  I could divide the final sum by 2 but this seems hacky.

Comment: You might start by simply computing the sum of the proper divisors of every number up to 10000 once, instead of recomputing it for every pair of numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big bottle-neck is the following for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 10000; j++) {
        if (isAmicablePair(i, j)) {
            System.out.println("(i, j) = (" + i + ", " + j + ")");
            total += (i + j);
        }
    }
}
```

This loops over 10000 * 10000 values, which is way too big, when you don't need to. Actually, you don't need `j` at all. By the way the problem is constructed, you know that you have to find `a` and `b` for which `d(a) = b` and `d(b) = a`.

This implies that you need to find `a` for which `d(d(a)) = a` (and `d(a) ≠ a`), thus dropping the need for a variable `b`. There is no need to find `b` by looping over all the possible values, we know by construction that when `a` is in an amicable pair, `b` will be equal to `d(a)`.

Consider this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
    if (isAmicable(i)) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        total += i;
    }
}
```

where the method `isAmicable` is a slight variation of your own:

```
public static boolean isAmicablePair(int a) {
    int b = sumOfProperDivisors(a);
    return b != a && sumOfProperDivisors(b) == a;
}
```

This implements the logic above of checking whether `d(d(a)) = a`.

With this code, the result is found very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to calculate the sum of divisors once for each number. Then just compare the answers to each other. That way you only do the heavy calculation 10,000 times instead of 10,000^2 times. O(n) instead of O(n^2).

To do the "compare the answers" part:

One option would be to put the numbers and sums in a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` such that the key is the number and the value is the sum. Iterate over the `Entry` set. While iterating, take the sum and use it as a key back into the same `Map`. If you get an entry for that, then they are amicable.

A quick sketch (i.e. I'm just winging it here):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numAndSum = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    numAndSum.put(i, sumOfProperDivisors(i);
}

for (Entry<Integer, Integer> anEntry: numAndSum) {
    Integer aNum = anEntry.getKey();
    Integer aSum = anEntry.getValue();
    if (numAndSum.contains(aSum)) {
        System.out.println("Amicable pair: " + aNum + ", " + aSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I'll loop through 1...10000 and maybe store the sum of proper divisors of each number using a hash.  But when you say "then just compare"...

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the inner loop (in your main enumeration of isAmicablePair(..)) to use:

```
for (j = i+1; j < 10000; j++)
{
  ...
}
```

Such that you are only evaluating unique pairs.